# Mean and variance of a time series

Tags: time-series, variance, mean, autocorrelation

Xt is a time series with the equation below:

Xt =   + 1/π (Xt-1)+ Zt                              t = 0,±1,±2, · · ·

where {Zt} ∼ WN(0, 1) and Zt is uncorrelated with Xs for each s < t.

I tried writing the expression of the mean; Is it correct?

**1 >** The expression of the mean μx = E[Xt] is

E[Xt] =  + 1/π E[Xt-1]

**2 >** Also I'm trying to write the equation of mean of the time series {Xt}.

How to find the variance expression of the variance σ^2X = V(Xt).